# How to use jdk.compiler module in jshell

Tags: javac, jshell

my jdk version is 17 and i want use `com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager` class, My startup parameters are

```sh
$ jshell --add-modules jdk.compiler
```

then i typed

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager;
```

I got a error like this:

```
|  Error:
|  package com.sun.tools.javac.file is not visible
|    (package com.sun.tools.javac.file is declared in module jdk.compiler, which does not export it to the unnamed module)
|  import com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager;
|         ^----------------------^
```

What should i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to JDK internal modules is not allowed since [JEP 403](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403).
To explicitly allow access in Java 17, one can use the option `--add-exports` while starting the JVM. This option also seems to work with `jshell`:

```
jshell --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
```

`--add-exports` is docummented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#extra-options-for-java):

```
--add-exports module/package=target-module(,target-module)*
    Updates module to export package to target-module, regardless of module declaration. The target-module can be all unnamed to export to all unnamed modules.
```